# MySQL show current connection info

Tags: mysql

I am in a MySQL terminal session but I don't know what server I am connected to, or what database I am connected to.

Is there a MySQL command that will tell me the host, port, and username and database I am using now?

Comment: Port can be picked up using "show variables like 'port'"

Comment: you will type "\s" to get the info of current database a

Comment: can  mysql  cli  always  show current db-name  just like mariadb `MySQL [sys]> `

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There are MYSQL functions you can use.  Like this one that resolves the user:

```
SELECT USER();
```

This will return something like `root@localhost` so you get the host and the user.

To get the current database run this statement:

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

Other useful functions can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Answer (score 152):

You can use the **status** command in MySQL client.

```
mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for Win32 (x86)

Connection id:          1
Current database:       test
Current user:           ODBC@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.8 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    gbk
Conn.  characterset:    gbk
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 7 min 16 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 21  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 33  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.48
--------------

mysql>
```

Comment: it is possible to output this data from a MySQL query via PHP?

Comment: Which version are you using to run this command? I think you are being confused between mysql client and mysqladmin program.
mysqladmin -u root -p status
This is my output:
Uptime: 79625  Threads: 3  Questions: 9903  Slow queries: 1  Opens: 106  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 99  Queries per second avg: 0.124
It does not show the information of database being connected as well.

Comment: If I executed this command on cmd of navicat, it gave me `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'status' at line 1` error. But If I run it on mysql client, it was ok.

Answer (score 47):

If you want to know the **port number of your local host on which Mysql** is running you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the port number on which MySQL is running.

---

If you want to know the **hostname of your Mysql** you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| hostname          | Dell  |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the hostname for mysql.

---

If you want to know the **username of your Mysql** you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
select user();   


mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the username for mysql.

Comment: Or you could use Yousui's answer of `mysql> status`, which returns all of this in a single command.

Comment: Yousui's answer does not include the hostname. Also, if you only wanted to return one of the specified values and not the whole list, these commands are very useful.