# SQL Query to check for mysql db users

Tags: mysql, database

I want to find out the users connected to a database. How do I perform this in SQL (mySQL)

Comment: seemed to be duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613704/mysql-show-current-connection-info

Comment: @lqez, actually, it doesn't seem to. It's a dupe. It's incredible how people don't do any effort to search before posting a question. The search box on the upper right corner in this site is there for some purpose, not to garnish the site for beauty, you know. You can use it.

Comment: No, I believe the OP wants to list all the active connections to the database. The linked question answers how to find out the user of the current connection.

Comment: @zrvan OMG. you're right. So I answered. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` will show the all connected sessions and you can pull out user list from it.

Comment: i need to validate a form containing a username and password, so this isnt going to help since at the state of the form i am not connected to the db. is there a sql query to show me all the registered users before i connect to that db, so i can validate if the username supplied is correct for the db

Comment: Then you can use 'user' table in 'mysql' database. It has usernames and passwords.

Comment: And without database connection, you cannot execute any sql query. However, just 'check authentication' is can be done by running shell command 'mysql -u[username] -p[password]' or mysql_connect() API.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't try it**:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

This will return the some information seen in the command line client, this query require PROCESS privilege for the user who made the query in order to see other client connection information.